# Error running vlc on Redhat Enterprise Linux 7

Tags: rhel, yum, dependencies, vlc, interface

I have installed vlc using following commands-

```
#>  yum install vlc
#>  yum install vlc-core
```

When i try to run vlc, i am getting the following error-

```
[0000000001bce288] core demux error: corrupt module: 
/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/access/libdvdnav_plugin.so
[0000000001bc99c8] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001b07118] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" 
initialization failed
[0000000001bc9b18] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus 
session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for 
X11
[0000000001bc9b18] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000001b07118] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization 
failed
[0000000001b07118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 
'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000000001bc99c8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.8 Weatherwax
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
```

I cant figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for

I believe you need to run it inside a graphical environment (gnome, kde, xfce, blackbox, etc..)
Also, is a good approach to run things as a less privileged user.

Comment: Running in gnome-environment.

Comment: was the gnome environment started by root or by another user? run a new instance of gnome-terminal and issue the command: $ id

Comment: Started gnome as  root but if you run vlc, it says " VLC is not supposed to run as root. Sorry." And if you change user under the same gnome, it gives out the same error.